# Loading icon in React.js with vanilla js, componentDidMount is never called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loader, flux

Trying to create a loading icon in my React.js project (application is build in React, gets data from Wordpress REST API and uses Flux to handle state). But componentDidMount() is never fired so my loading icon never fades.. This is my app.js:

```
class App extends Component {

  templates = {
    'about': About,
    'contact': Contact,
    'archive': Archive
  }

  buildRoutes(data){
    return data.pages.map((page, i) => {
      return(
        <Route
          key={i}
          component={this.templates[page.slug]}
          path={`/${page.slug}`}
          exact
        />
      )
    })
  }

  run(){
    DataActions.getPages((response) => {
      render(
        <div>
          <div className="loaderSmall" id="loaderSmall">
            <div className="pixel-loader"></div>
          </div>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Header />
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
                {this.buildRoutes(response)}
                <Route render={() => { return <Redirect to="/" />}} />
              </Switch>
              <Footer />
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div> , document.getElementById('app')
      );
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
    console.log("componentDidMount");
  }

  // Fade out site-loader
  handleLoad() {
    console.log("CALLED");
    var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("loaderSmall");
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
      if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
          fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
      }
      if (fadeTarget.style.opacity < 0.1) {
          clearInterval(fadeEffect);
      } else {
          fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

..and I get no errors:

[image]

Comment: Your fade-out works for me, did you get any error??

Comment: No noo errors :( @AlejandroMontilla

Comment: I've posted an answer, the problem might be the `render()` method. Try that and let me know.

Comment: Is the event "load" supported in all browsers?

Comment: @Sulthan I would think so, it works when I add the handleLoad() in another project - so it seems to be the issue that handleLoad() is never called in my project :(

Comment: Seeing your crash log, your app obviously crashes somewhere else (`Home.render`). For that reason the event is not probably triggered. Fix your crash first.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes but how .. The Home component works fine when I have the app.js code stated in the top - so it's obviosly something wrong with my new app.js code below that I cant for my life figure out .. this.state.pages just returns a empty array :(

Comment: @fransBernhard, small fix: you have `className="loaderSmall" id="loaderSmall"` change one (probably the class name). I cant see the problem, but if I were you, I will rewrite a simple `render`that return just `<div>`'s, and then adding your components. In that way you can find where is the problems. Do that make sense??

Comment: I did that in my second attempt at app.js above - but then the rendering of Home component crashes as @Sulthan claryfied. So I need to figure out how to get my Wordpress pages from DataActions.getPages and set them inside the <Switch><Route></..></..> section - cause it seem to be because of that it crashes - "{this.state.pages}" is a empty array

Comment: When looking at the errors - all the <Route>s (console.log "routs: ") is rendered after errors - which means they probably are not available when {Home} is trying to render. Maybe thats the issue .. I'll keep banging my head against the wall

Answer (score 0):

Your code looked fine for me at the beginning, but when I looked more closely I could see that 
your code is missing the `render()` method. I've added a "stub" render and it worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app"></div>
    <img id="loaderSmall" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">

    <script type="text/babel">
        
      class App extends React.Component {
      
        // When Component has rendered, window.addEventListener adds event "load" and calls handleLoad function
        componentDidMount() {
          window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
        }
      
        // Fade out site-loader
        handleLoad() {
          var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("loaderSmall");
          console.log(fadeTarget);
          var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
              if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
                  fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
              }
              if (fadeTarget.style.opacity < 0.1) {
                  clearInterval(fadeEffect);
              } else {
                  fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
              }
          }, 300);
        }
        
        render(){return <div></div>}  // This was missing
      }
       
      ReactDOM.render(
          <App/>,
          document.getElementById("app")
      )
        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My render() method is inside the "run()" method, I'm using flux to get backend data from wordpress rest api - and this is the only way I know to get data .. But it's great that it works for you! That means that I simply need to figure out my configuration :)

Comment: Well I'm just a React beginner, to put the `render` in that way is new for me. But if you do that to get data from your back-end you could try `this.state` in your Class and go with a "regular" render. Do that make sense to your case?

Comment: I will try! @Alejandro

Comment: Didn't work that either :( Something is happening so that my handleLoad function is not called .. @Alejandro

Comment: @fransBernhard Can you post your updated code? or share some link so I can see your code?

Comment: I tried the handleLoad() in another project where I don't get data from Wordpress and wrote a normal "render()" function, and then it all worked - so I tried to reconstruct my app.js - but then I cant figure out how to get my pages from Wordpress.. I'll post my updated code and ping you when it's up! My React project is here: https://github.com/fransbernhard/wordpressReactSassWebpack and my wordpress installation is here: https://github.com/fransbernhard/wordpress-theme

Comment: I posted my new app.js code above, a pathetic attempt to involve state - there is surely a better way, but I can't figure it out :(